# Which is the most effective way to get all the results of aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
GET my-index-*/my-type/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "script" : "code"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dates": {
          "date_range": {
            "field": "created_time",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": "2017-12-09T00:00:00.000",
                "to": "2017-12-09T16:00:00.000"
              },
              {
                "from": "2017-12-10T00:00:00.000",
                "to": "2017-12-10T16:00:00.000"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "total_count": {
          "sum_bucket": {
          "buckets_path": "dates._count"
          }
        },
        "bucket_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "totalCount": "total_count"
            },
            "script": "params.totalCount == 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this query is a bunch of buckets. What I need is the list of keys of my buckets. The problem is the aggregation result size is 10 by default, after getting those 10, my `bucket_filter` filters them by total count, and I get only some of those 10. I need to have all the results, which means I need to specify `"size" = n`, where `n` is the distinct count of `code` values, so that I don't lose any data. I have billions of documents, so in my case `n` is about 30.000. When I tried executing the query, "Out of memory" occurred on cluster, so I guess it's not the best idea. Is there a good way to get all the results for my query?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not recommended for high carnality fields with 30K unique values. The reason is because of memory cost and the large amount of data it needs to collect from the shards as you've discovered. It might work, but then you need more memory...

A more efficient solution is to use the `Scroll API` and specify in `fields` in your search request the values you want to retrieve from a field, and then store these values either in your client in-memory or stream it.

*Update*: since ES 6.5 this has been possible with Composite aggregations, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html